# Make a thread to run a Postgres stored function

Tags: java, postgresql, thread-safety

I have a stored function that will remove something from the database, but since it could be a very long task, I want to make a thread to execute this function, and let the user keep on doing what he is doing.

Currently I have the following:

The DAO:

```
    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void deleteAll()
    {
        Session session = (Session) entityManager.getDelegate();
        session.doWork(new Work()
        {
            @Override
            public void execute(Connection connection) throws SQLException
            {
                try
                {
                    // stored function is currently named delete_function()
                    CallableStatement deleteAll= connection.prepareCall("{call delete_function()}");
                    purgeArchived.execute();
                    purgeArchived.close();
                }
                catch (SQLException exception)
                {
                    LOGGER.warn(exception);
                }
            }
        });
}
```

Im afraid when i call getDao.deleteAll() in the rest service, this will be in working for a really long time if the database has lot of stuff to delete. How do I create a thread to do the same thing? Or will this create a thread and execute the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you will need to make your own thread for this.  Probably the simplest thing to do is to copy the entire body of your current `deleteAll()` method to the `run()` method of a new class, that extends `Thread`.  Assuming you've called that class `DeleteAllThread`, you'd then replace your method above with

```
@Override
public void deleteAll() {
    new DeleteAllThread().start();
}
```

Comment: Careful when creating a thread when using Hibernate. Since OP hasn't explained how the transaction managements is done, creating a thread where Hibernate will execute its methods could be external to the common transaction manager and this transaction will be rollbacked after being executed.

Comment: Good point, @LuiggiMendoza.  Obviously, I expect this to work; but I think the best thing for the OP to do is test this very carefully, both in cases where other transactions are committed and where other transactions fail.

Comment: Can you explain your comment a little bit more? Rollbacked after being executed? sorry @LuiggiMendoza

Comment: @JennyC for example, I had this problem when Spring managed the transaction manager used by Hibernate. When opening a thread on my own inside a method where Spring injected its transaction manager, this transaction manager was not aware of the operations done in my thread, so no matter how many times I naively added `session.commit()` in my thread, it won't work because the transaction manager is not handled in my thread but in the thread where Spring controls it. So, I had to move the commit after the thread finished its work. Not sure if this may apply to your case as well.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza - This is really important information that doesn't really belong down in the comments.  May I ask you to do one of two things please?  **EITHER** (1) Edit your information into my answer, however you see fit, and I will Community-Wiki the answer.  **OR** (2) Post your own answer, using as much or as little of my content as you feel like, and I will delete mine and upvote yours.

Comment: You can take the content in my comments and adapt it in your answer. I'm ok with that.

Comment: @DavidWallace Hey David, shouldnt I be overriding the start() method instead of the run() method if i am calling newThread.start()?

Comment: No, absolutely not.  The way a `Thread` works is that you override `run` then call `start`.  When you call `start`, a new thread is started, and that new thread runs the `run` method.

Comment: @DavidWallace Ok, and when you said you needed session.commit() after thread does it work, do you mean add a session.commit() after new DeleteAllThread().start();?

Comment: Im having the problem you are having maybe? The session.doWork is not beening executed as it seems.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to take a look at using a [ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html). This may make things a little cleaner for you.  [Here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/executorservice.html#executorservice-example) is a simple example of how to use an ExecutorService.

Comment: [This comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27048905/make-a-thread-to-run-a-postgres-stored-function#comment42615854_27049080) applies for your answer as well.